# How can I build older AIR apps with a newer version of the AIR SDK without updating the application descriptor file?

Tags: actionscript-3, air

Does anybody know how to build an AIR application made with an earlier version of the SDK (say 3.8, or 3.9) with a newer version of the AIR SDK (4.0, for instance) without altering the namespace version in the application descriptor xml file?

Adobe claims in the [release notes for AIR SDK 4.0 (beta) (pdf)](http://labsdownload.adobe.com/pub/labs/flashruntimes/shared/air4_flashplayer13_releasenotes.pdf):

> If your application
>   does not require the new AIR 4.0 API's and behavior, you are not required to update the namespace. However, we recommend all users start
>   using the AIR 4.0 namespace even if you are not yet taking advantage of the new
>   capabilities.

and I've seen that in earlier release notes too but I've always had to update the namespace anyway, to prevent compiler error messages like this one:

`Namespace 3.9 in the application descriptor file should be equal or higher than the minimum version 4.0 required by AIR SDK .`

Can it be fixed by a compiler argument, or something else?

Comment: Why do you not want to update the namespace? It can get annoying, yes, but it is simple to do and ensures you have full access to that version of the SDK. That said, I don't think I've ever been able to get around that compiler error.

Comment: Well, one reason is that in Flash Builder you can have only one AIR SDK active, and when one member of our team upgrades, that means that everyone must upgrade, as soon as someone changes the app descriptor. And it's a waste of time to have to revisit older applications just to update the sdk version number, if Adobe claims it's not necessary.

Comment: You can only have one active, but you can have unlimited loaded. All you have to do is switch between them. The namespace has a side-purpose of helping your problem: ensuring that all devs are on the same SDK version. Instead of changing the SDK each time, you should be setting the SDK on a per-project basis. No one should **ever** upgrade the SDK unless the **entire** team is on-board with the decision (not just from a Flash Builder perspective, but from a dev perspective)

Comment: @JoshJanusch, I'm curious how you set AIR SDK's in Flash Builder on a per-project basis. All I know is that Flash Builder 4.7 has one AIR SDK it points to for all projects - in the `eclipse/plugins/com.adobe.flash.compiler_4.7.0.349722` folder (I'm not talking about Flex SDK's here). You're right about requiring all devs on the same project to use the same SDK, but now we have to use the same SDK for all projects, regardless of what team you belong to.

Comment: Oh, you're not using Flex. My mistake. Flex does allow you to switch them easily. Not sure why they never implemented such a feature for AS3 projects. I don't know what else to say here. Sorry for not being of much help.